# How to return a collection in code from a Meteor project created with meteor-boilerplate?

Tags: meteor-collections

**This is the code I am using:**

```
Contacts = new Mongo.Collection('contacts');
Template.contact.helpers({
  contact: function() {
  return Contacts.find({});
  }
});
```

**However the HTML is not returning the collection.**

Comment: And how does your html file looks like?

Comment: <template name= "contact">
     <div class="container">
 <h3>Contacts:</h3>
 <ul>
  {{#each contact}}  
     <li>{{name}}</li>        
  {{/each}}
 </ul> 
    </div>
</template>

Comment: And you are sure you have records in Contacts collection? Try typing in console Contacts.find().fetch()

Comment: In browser console it returns empty array. The issue is if I try with simple application it gives expected result. But here I'm not understanding where actual problem is...

Comment: If you dont have any record then obviously it wont return anything. Type into console `Contacts.insert({name: "example"});`

Comment: On screen inserted name appears for a moment. And following is shown on console                                                                                       Contacts.insert({name: "Neo"});  
"ecphJTLuMNTo4PcDT"
"insert failed: Method not found" meteor.js:887

Comment: I'm guessing you're used to having `autopublish` and `insecure` activated, and your boilerplate generator is turning them off (as it should). The solution is to look up publish/subscribe and allow/deny/methods.

Comment: Or simply add those packages just for testing purposes `meteor add autopublish insecure`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [the meteor-boilerplate website](http://boilerplate.meteor.com/), you can see that

> "insecure" and "autopublish" are removed by default!

By default, Meteor includes the `autopublish` package which makes all data in the database available to the client. This is only suitable for early development, and any real project will remove it. So meteor-boilerplate removes it by default.

Without `autopublish`, you will need to publish the data yourself. You can try this:

```js
// server code
Meteor.publish("contacts", function () {
    return Contacts.find();
});

// client code
Meteor.subscribe("contacts");
```

Then your existing code should work.

For more information, see [publish and subscribe](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish) from the Meteor docs.

Comment: Your answer is needed as well in addition to mine. I thought providing the example link would be explain it further. Either-way hopefully it helps.Also you are assuming the Contacts collection has a field name contacts.  I figured name made more sense for a collection of contacts you would have a field called name not contacts.

Comment: Thanks #user3374348 I have to go through "publish and subscribe " part. I haven't looked at server code.

Answer (score 0):

**In your HTML file you need to define the template:**

```
<template name="Contacts"> 
{{#each contacts}}
    {{name}}
{{/each}}
</template>
```

**In your java script you would define the helper template and return the Contacts collection.**

```
Contacts = new Mongo.Collection('contacts');
    Template.Contacts.helpers({
        'contacts': function(){
            return Contact.find()
        }

});
```

Check out this tutorial for more information - [How To Create Templates in Meteor - Meteor Tutorial](http://meteortips.com/book/templates/)

Comment: That was me. The helper should be called "Contacts", not "name". I'll remove the downvote if you fix that. But besides, if you look at the comments, you can see that peter pawar knows how to #each over a cursor returned by a helper, the problem is that it's the data isn't published.

Comment: It is an example of including the html needed and displaying a reference to a field from the contacts collection. The question was not very clear that is why i tried to change it to make more sense. Even the question title you changed is basically the same but if you think it is different then that is fine.